# ogone string issue

Tags: php, payment

I have a test account from Ogone, and I'm trying to test a payment system. I built a string with the bare minimum of parameters, for testing purposes:

```
$ogoSHAstring = "AMOUNT=" . $amount . $signature . 
                "CURRENCY=" . $currency. $signature . 
                "LANGUAGE=" . $language . $signature . 
                "ORDERID=" . $orderId . $signature . 
                "PSPID=" . $pspId . $signature;
```

It results in a string that looks like this:

```
AMOUNT=990MySecretPassphrase!!CURRENCY=EURMySecretPassphrase!!LANGUAGE=nl_NLMySecretPassphrase!!ORDERID=67MySecretPassphrase!!PSPID=MyPSPIDMySecretPassphrase!!
```

Which is hashed to

```
1B8B605EAEF8E2FD9350958C0B152E22FD61FADB
```

The form that is sent looks like this:

```
<form id='ogone' action='https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='AMOUNT' value='$amount' />
    <input type='hidden' name='CURRENCY' value='$currency' />
    <input type='hidden' name='LANGUAGE' value='$language' />
    <input type='hidden' name='ORDERID' value='$orderId' />
    <input type='hidden' name='PSPID' value='$pspId' />
    <input type='hidden' name='SHASIGN' value='$ogoSHAsign' />
</form>
```

But I keep getting an error:

```
unknown order/1/r/
```

These are my settings:

[image]
[image]

any help?

Answer (score 11):

If you receive the error `unknown order/1/r/` this is not due to your SHA calculation. It is due to your referring URL. As you have configured in your `Data and origin verification` tab, your form should be calling Ogone from `http://www.someurl.com/php/ogone.php`.

And I guess you are calling them from another URL. So I advice you to remove the referer URL from their configuration screen while you are testing. Or use the one you are actually using.

If you would have a SHA error you'd receive the `unknown order/1/s/` error.

Lastly your form is not correct either. You are just writing your PHP variable names in your form, rather than really `echo`'ing them. Change it to:

```
<form id='ogone' action='https://secure.ogone.com/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='AMOUNT' value='<?=$amount?>' />
    <input type='hidden' name='CURRENCY' value='<?=$currency?>' />
    <input type='hidden' name='LANGUAGE' value='<?=$language?>' />
    <input type='hidden' name='ORDERID' value='<?=$orderId?>' />
    <input type='hidden' name='PSPID' value='<?=$pspId?>' />
    <input type='hidden' name='SHASIGN' value='<?=$ogoSHAsign?>' />
</form>
```